# Creating indexes after data load Vs Before data load in a large table

Tags: sql-server, index, ssis

I have a huge sql server table of size 430 GB on one server A.

I needed to copy the table as it is to a new server B, so I created an empty table on the server B and moved all data from A to B using SSIS package/job - this took me almost 30+ hours.

Now the data copy is finished and the big task is to build the indexes.

Was I correct in taking this approach, or should I have loaded the data in already indexed table on server B ?

-----------------------------TABLE---------------

```
CREATE TABLE [CCTSwapForward].[SWAP_DATA](
    [SwapData_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Contract_ID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DataSourceName] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Direction] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [StatusDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TargetCurrencyCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [SettlementCurrencyCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [TargetAmount] [float] NULL,
    [SettlementAmount] [float] NULL,
    [ConfirmationNo] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ItemNo] [int] NULL,
    [ExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Original_TargetAmount] [float] NULL,
    [Original_SettlementAmount] [float] NULL,
    [PartyID] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PrimaryAssetClass] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [SecondaryAssetClass] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [PriceNotationType] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [PriceNotationValue] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Addn_PriceNotationType] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Addn_PriceNotationValue] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ProductIDPrefix] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ProductIDValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [AllocationIndicator] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ExecutionTS] [datetime] NULL,
    [VerificationType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ExecutionVenuePrefix] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ExecutionVenue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ClearingDCOValue] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Collateralized] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [LastReporteddt] [datetime] NULL,
    [Confirmationdt] [datetime] NULL,
    [ConfirmationType] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [Valuationdt] [datetime] NULL,
    [MTMValue] [float] NULL,
    [MTMCurrency] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [ReportingJurisdiction] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ValueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExchangeRate] [float] NULL,
    [TradePartyRole] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TradePartyPrefix] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TradePartyValue] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ReportingObligation] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [USPersonIndicator] [bit] NULL,
    [FinEntityIndicator] [bit] NULL,
    [ClientOrder_ID] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDetail_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Batch_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status_ID] [int] NULL,
    [initdt] [datetime] NULL,
    [initid] [int] NULL,
    [upddt] [datetime] NULL,
    [updid] [int] NULL,
    [ReportingPartyLEI] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ProcessCenter] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TargetAmount_NDec] [int] NULL,
    [SettlementAmount_NDec] [int] NULL,
    [ExchangeRate_NDec] [int] NULL,
    [MTMRate] [float] NULL,
    [LastUpdatedTS] [datetime] NULL,
    [Client_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Office_ID] [int] NULL,
    [IsInterafiliate] [bit] NULL,
    [TreasuryToBranchRate] [float] NULL,
    [ActualValueDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SpreadRevenueInSettlementCurrency] [float] NULL,
    [SettlementToUSDRate] [float] NULL,
    [ReportingCurrencyToUSDRate] [float] NULL,
    [TradeCurrencyToUSDRate] [float] NULL,
    [BranchCurrency] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [FirstTradeDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Action] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TransactionType] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [LifeCycleEvent] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [TPDomicile] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [TP1Branch] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TP2FinancialJurisdiction] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TP2NonFinancialJurisdiction] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [MasterAgreementDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ReportingDelegation_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RelatedClientOrder_ID] [int] NULL,
    [RelatedOrderDetail_ID] [int] NULL,
    [ReportingDelegationModel] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ExtractDatetimeUTC] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsNDF] [bit] NULL,
    [FixingDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [SettlementExchangeBasis] [varchar](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

--------------------INDEX---------------------------



USE [ODS]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Batch_ID_SwapData_ID] ON [CCTSwapForward].[SWAP_DATA]
(
    [Batch_ID] ASC,
    [SwapData_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [ODS]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Contract_ID_SwapData_ID] ON [CCTSwapForward].[SWAP_DATA]
(
    [Contract_ID] ASC,
    [SwapData_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


USE [ODS]
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [idx_SWAPDATA_ID] ON [CCTSwapForward].[SWAP_DATA]
(
    [SwapData_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: did you presize the target DB?................

Comment: Could you please provide the table structure including all index definitions - this will have a big impact.

Comment: @George.Palacios attached

Comment: @MitchWheat, i am sorry , not sure what exactly you mean by presize ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that your table is very wide, and the indexes very narrow, creating non-clustered indexes on the table following the load should be preferred.

In this instance I would have:

1. Create the new table with the Clustered Index in place - this is because the process of converting a heap into a clustered index is computationally expensive.
2. Load the data into the table, in the order of the clustered index SwapData_ID
3. Using BULK INSERT (ensuring the operation is minimally logged), load into the table
4. Create the non-clustered indexes

The above approach should be optimal given your scenario.

There is of course then other questions around:

Data drift (will the source data change during your load process? Do these changes need to be taken across)

DR (is log shipping enabled? In this case the recovery model may need to be changed to bulk-logged)

Log file sizing (You'll need to ensure your log file is big enough to accommodate for the non-clustered index creations)

Presizing the database (ensuring it doesn't auto-grow during the load)

but these all seem to be slightly outside the context of what you're asking.

Comment: @KumarHarsh we do 'merge' on this table every 30 minutes , daily , rowcount of each iteration is around 50,000+

Comment: will partitioning the table help ?

Comment: @AjinkyaPujari In what sense? What are your thoughts?

Comment: was wondering about performance of building indexes on partitioned table VS non partitioned table. your thoughts ?

Comment: @AjinkyaPujari I would start a new question about that if I were you.

Answer (score -5):

It is always a good idea to index before data migration
When you are migrating huge volumes of data, consider these things

1) Storage: Includes RAM,memory and network latency of the source and target server
2) Incremental Loading: I wouldn't do 30 Hours of data loading into the destination as it will consume very large resources
3) Indexes: Consider what indexes you will need in each table and avoid the need for many indexes (non-clustered)

Indexing After Data migration:

As your table size is 430+ GB, indexing the table would take the same amount of time as it took for data migration.

Consider A data table to join for data migration and align data types of destination table

Comment: Indexing the table would take the same amount of time as it took for data migration - could you back this up at all?